# alacritty receives strange keystrokes when switching workspace

Tags: command-line, workspaces

My setup:

- Ubuntu 19.10, up to date, quite fresh install without too many tweaks
- installed Alacritty via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mmstick76/alacritty; sudo apt update; sudo apt install alacritty`
- shell if `fish`, installed via `sudo apt install fish`

When I switch workspace so that I **end up** on Alacritty, my shell prompt seems to receive weird keystrokes: `[1;7A` gets added to my prompt:

[image]

Any idea what happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the Alacritty developers and it seems to be a bug from Alacritty which should be solved now in the current “master” branch:

https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/3229

So I guess I'll just wait for the update to be shipped through the PPA.
I'll update this answer when the bug is fixed in PPA version.

Apparently this only appears under X11. I was surprised to learn that I am running X11, I though Ubuntu switched to Wayland by default.